# How to extract a particular substring from a regex in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying this way:

```
 var patt1 =/[a-zA-Z\s]+:[a-zA-Z0-9\S]*/g;
```

This code would extract the pattern `<string>:<someString>`
The `<someString>` is what i wish to extract.
I am aware that the `slice()` method could be used to do this, but I'm not entirely sure about how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just a note on your regex**: `\S` matches any non-whitespace character including `a-zA-Z0-9`. Please check the requirements for the `[a-zA-Z0-9\S]` character class. Now, you can just replace it with `\S`. Now, you might as well use `/[a-z\s]+:(\S*)/gi` (it will match the same texts).

Now, using *your* regex as an example, here is how you can leverage the *capturing* mechanism:

```
/[a-zA-Z\s]+:([a-zA-Z0-9\S]*)/g
             ^              ^
```

Use it with `RegExp#exec()` in a loop to access Group 1 value.

```js
var re = /[a-zA-Z\s]+:([a-zA-Z0-9\S]*)/g; 
var str = 'Some:Word Another:Word2';

document.body.innerHTML += "Results:<br/>";
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.body.innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: i'm new to this,so could i have an example of this as a reference, thanking you in advance

Comment: Please pay attention to my note, I think you need to reconsider the regex pattern. Without more details, I cannot help you with the regex pattern adjustment. Now, you might as well use `/[a-z\s]+:(\S*)/gi` (it will match the same texts).

Comment: Okay, i'll try that. i did have a feeling my regex wasn't correct, thanks for pointing it out.